# SELECT SUM(column) INTO @variable in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

`SELECT SUM(column) INTO @variable FROM tabl2 WHERE column2 = NEW.column in MySQL update Trigger returns NULL`.

My code is as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER `users_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE profit DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT SUM(PROFIT) INTO @profit FROM trades WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN AND PROFIT > 0;

    UPDATE user_details SET profit = @profit WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN;
END;
```

However the same query when executed separately I get data. This is driving me crazy. Please can someone suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you please provide complete trigger ?

Comment: Updated the question with the trigger code now.

Comment: Are you sure there are rows to be SUM-ed in the `trades` table at the time the trigger executes? Also try removing the `DECLARE profit..` you are not using it anyway.

Comment: Yes, there are records to be summed up. As I said, if I execute the query separately I do get a value, the query returns a NULL only when executed within the trigger.

Comment: Just a thought. Could this be a lock issue on the second table?

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. Apparently MySQL doesnt recognize both the variable name and the column name to have the same name. Because I was using a variable called @profit and the column name was also PROFIT (MySQL setting of lower-case-tables was enabled), MySQL incorrectly assumed the column name to be the variable name. When I changed the variable name to profits, the same query worked!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with MySQL. My suspicion is that the cause of this might be due to the "lower_case_table_names" setting. Apparently the variable name that I declared in the trigger and the column name in the table "trades" were exactly the same (profit). As a result MySQL incorrectly assumed that the aggregate function SUM(profit) needs to performed against the variable rather than the column. Its strange that MySQL is not very strict that variable names must be prefixed by @.

As soon as I changed the variable name to total_profit, the same query started to work!

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `users_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE profit DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT @profit:=SUM(PROFIT) FROM trades WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN AND PROFIT > 0;

    UPDATE user_details SET profit = @profit WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN;
END;

Or if you want to use into:

CREATE TRIGGER `users_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE profit DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT SUM(PROFIT) FROM trades WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN AND PROFIT > 0 INTO @profit;

    UPDATE user_details SET profit = @profit WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN;
END;
```

Comment: SELECT @profit:=SUM(PROFIT) FROM trades WHERE LOGIN = new.LOGIN AND PROFIT > 0; Is this valid syntax??

Comment: The SELECT INTO returns NULL as well :(!

Comment: yes, I believe these are valid syntax, you can always test. update your trigger, and do some test, make sure all conditions from your WHERE are all true.

Comment: SELECT @profit := SUM(PROFIT) in a trigger gives the error  "#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger"

Comment: I believe you mean SET @profit := SELECT SUM(PROFIT)..., which again returns NULL when executed within the trigger.

Comment: yes I think you can use SET or you can also use what you are using right now (INTO). If the select statement returns NULL, then you have no data that you can put on your variable.

Comment: As I said, there is data. When the same code is executed separate for the same LOGIN, I get data, but the query returns NULL only when executed within trigger. For example the LOGIN=1000 has 3 records in trades with the profit adding up to 3000, but this query returns NULL when executed within the trigger!!

Comment: Actually, there's nothing wrong with the syntax you posted above, you just need some troubleshooting steps, divide the query, execute separately and check what is the main culprit. There's something wrong maybe with your understanding of "trigger" or with the use of exclamation point. :)

Comment: Turns out that the problem was caused due to lower-case-table setting enabled and both the column name and the variable name used in the query being the same. As soon as I changed the variable name to profits, the query worked! Looks like a bug in MySQL!